# How to make a new column using 2 criteria

Tags: r

I am trying to make a column showing the financial year of a date in r studio.

I currently have 2 columns, one showing the month (as a number) and one showing the year.

I would like the third column to display the financial year, by picking out:

if month <= 3 & year = 2017, then financial year= FY1617

if month >= 4 & year = 2017, then financial year= FY1718

etc. etc.

It seems like this should be a simple thing to do, but I've tried lots of things and can't work it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(
    fy = ifelse(
      month <= 3,
      paste0("FY", year-2001, year-2000),
      paste0("FY", year-2000, year-1999)
    )
  )
```

That would be the dead-simple solution...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not the most elegant way to do it, but it should go

```r
df <- data.frame(month = c(1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 9, 12, 11, 6, 8, 7, 10), 
                 year = c(2018, 2018, 2017, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2017, 2018))

v_fy <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (df$month[i] < 4) {
    fy <- paste("FY", substr(df$year[i]-1, 3, 4), substr(df$year[i], 3, 4), sep = "")
    v_fy <- c(v_fy, fy)
  } else {
    fy <- paste("FY", substr(df$year[i], 3, 4), substr(df$year[i] + 1, 3, 4), sep = "")
  v_fy <- c(v_fy, fy)
}
  
}

df$fy <- v_fy
```

Comment: quite inefficient, too, using a for-loop instead of vectorized functions such as `ifelse`. you're missing out on a core utility of having R in the first place. ([here](https://rpubs.com/daspringate/vectorisation) is one example for what a world of difference vectorized code makes vs. loops)